# android - firebase in app location tracking

Tags: android, firebase, geolocation

I want to apply a in app location tracker in android. this will show all friends, using the same app by synchronizing contact numbers and allow to get there location on map after request approval. Can any body help with any idea for how to proceed? I am new in android and i will be using this in a app which is already using firebase authentication and and chat function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can uses [geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) for the location

> GeoFire simply stores locations with string keys

Comment: Hi, thanks a ton for kind answer.
but GeoFire allows us to query all keys within a geographic area using GeoQuery objects.
My concern is mainly to know registered users from same, also i want to get location of only users which are in my phone contact list.

Comment: if possible, then user can turn off location sharing for some other particular user